# Weyl Semimetal and Fermi Velocity

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators, weyl-semimetal

In a Weyl semimetal, the Nielson-Ninomiya theorem enforces the fact that number of positive and negative chirality Weyl points must be equal.

Is there any restriction on the form of the Weyl points? That is to say, given a pair of Weyl points, can the positive chirality point have a different Fermi velocity than the negative chirality point (in the absence of symmetries relating the two)?

If it is true that the Fermi velocities are allowed to be different, are there any physical consequences of this difference?

Answer (score -2):

The existence of Weyl fermions [appears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_semimetal) to be dependent on the repeating structure of the crystal lattice, specifically translation symmetry. Based on paragraph three of this [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys4275), it looks like the Weyl points will even accommodate defects in Weyl semimetals.

Equal positive and negative chirality Weyl points are imposed on a Weyl semimetal as a way to ensure that it does not spontaneously accumulate chiral charge from Fermi arcs. Anything you do to slow the Fermi velocity of one chirality will prompt other translationally symmetrical 'cells' to interact with the disrupted pair in order to regain charge/momentum balance.

According to the talk (at 13:00) given [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Du5z7NEYYDw) by Carlo Beenakker, individual Weyl cones can appear to have a unidirectional current. Charge is conserved by the interaction of left and right-handed cones across the bulk. In the situation you discuss, perhaps there are an even number of left handed and right-handed cones in the bulk, but they are not distributed evenly – this creates a ‘Chiral Chemical Potential Difference’.

The idea is that the uneven charge allows uneven current to appear over short distances. Changes in current produce a measurable magnetic field termed a ‘Chiral Magnetic Effect’, which is discussed (at 17:00). **Experimental evidence for CME from CCPD does not appear to exist.** [However](http://www.mwdeem.rice.edu/djearl/htp_jmc2001.pdf), computer simulations and indirect measurements suggest CCPD theory is valid.

Given that Weyl Fermions of both chirality are massless,  will travel at the same speed through electric gradient or changing magnetic field. The speaker proposes a experiment which can produce evidence of CME (at 23:10) which needs a seed magnetic field to influence direction that left and right-handed fermi arcs bend.

*It does not appear possible to preferentially accelerate a chiral current without using a CCPD, which is experimentally unconfirmed.* The proposed magnetic field seeding will affect Weyl fermions equally because they have the same (zero) mass.

Contrast this with electrons and holes, where mobility is different for each ‘particles’.

### Saved from discussion below:

Consider the following simplified example:
"We have 1 *'coulomb'* of right-chirality weyl fermions and 2 *'coulombs'* left-chirality weyl fermions available to a subgroup of atoms in a weyl semimetal, which is chirality balanced in bulk.

[image: CCPD depiction]

*Chiral Chemical Potential Difference with cross-section.*

**A**: The *'chiralstatic?'* repulsion produced by their respective concentration gradients causes a current of 1 'ampere' of right-chiral fermions to travel **(faster)** across a $10mm^2$ cross section of the weyl semimetal as 1 'ampere' of left-chiral fermions travel **(slower)** in the opposite direction for a short period of time.
**B**: This happens until the chiralities are still imbalanced (.50 *'coulombs right'*, .50 *'coulombs left'*) but have non-equal concentration gradients such that all subsequent flow has $I_{NET}$=.25
*'ampere'* left-chiral fermions."

This example simplifies the current flow from what would obviously be a changing number to a constant number, but there are still two distinct periods. A has equal current, so by $Magfield=\frac{\mu_o∗I}{2∗pi∗d}$ the current carrying cross section has no magnetic field. **B** has a non-equal current, producing a temporary magnetic field. **B** would be an observable physical consequence, but it does originate from the *faster* speed of the right-chiral current. It originates from the net current of .25 left-chiral *'amperes'* during stage **B**.

Stage **A** has a net magnetic field of zero because the dense left-chiral current appears magnetically opposite to the fewer *contracted reference frame* right-chiral fermions that are going **faster**.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to improve this answer, perhaps you were asking about semimetals without defects?

Comment: This answer doesn't have enough rigor; it appears to be mostly guesswork. For example, no explanation is given regarding what the relationship between pseudogaps and the chirality restriction. Translation symmetry is assumed to hold, as you can't even have a band structure, much less a Weyl semimetal, without it.

Comment: Speculation on psuedogaps has been removed and discussion prior to the Carlo Beenakker talk has been rephrased to focus on the chiral charge (or uneven handedness).

Comment: The question is asking regarding the theory of a Weyl semimetal, not so much about the experimental status. This doesn't answer the question regarding Fermi velocities nor potential theoretical observable consequences. As a side note, there is (controversial) evidence for CME in magnetoresistance measurements.

Comment: No preferential acceleration of chiral current, in my understanding, means no difference in Fermi velocity for Weyl Fermions. (Not to say that velocity **is** acceleration by any means.) If you could preferentially accelerate chiral currents, the observable consequence would be a chiral magnetic field _or chiral magnetic effects_. (Please notify me if this should be added to my answer.)

Comment: I disagree. For example, a different population of left and right-moving fermions with different velocities can lead to zero net current.

Comment: I'm sorry, which part do you disagree with? I agree with your last comment with regards to net current. [Comments are not for extended discussion, but I don't know if I have the tools to move this to a chat client.]

Comment: I disagree with the statement "no preferential acceleration of chiral current means no difference in Fermi velocity".

Comment: No, my point is that you have argued that the fermi velocities are the same, and i disagree that you can draw that conclusion from your argument. The whole point of the second half of the question is to ask what happens if the fermi velocities are different, so if they are the same it becomes moot. Ultimately this is a question regarding the mathematical restrictions on the form of weyl nodes starting from some lattice hamiltonian, in the spirit of the nielson-ninomiya theorem.

Comment: I have absorbed my last three comments into my answer, please read it as I now suppose you _can_ change the velocity of the weyl fermions. I do not have the expertise to mathematically model a local asymmetry lattice hamiltonian as an exception to the nielson-ninomiya no-go theorem, but my thinking is that you can achieve uneven velocity using concentration gradients.

Comment: The whole point of the weyl point is that the band structure is linear (locally) near the weyl point, so the fermi velocity at each weyl point is fixed. I don't think you can change the fermi velocity by changing the chemical potential.

Comment: "-The whole point of the second half of the question is to ask what happens if the fermi velocities are different, so if they are the same it becomes moot.-" Are you looking for both a non-Chiral Chemical Potential induced difference in fermi velocity _and_ an observable consequence?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81541/discussion-between-human-filament-and-aaron).